# explicitly whitelist every page using robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I need to allow only specific pages at some site. Let's say:

```
/
/page1 
/page2
...
```

Now I don't get how to whitelist the root page at robots.txt

```
Disallow: /         # block everything
Allow: /page1
Allow: /page2
Allow: ?            # how to allow the / ???
```

And I'm stuck here, because **Allow: /** will allow everything back

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a $ sign which indicates the end of the string.

For example

Allow: /$

If you go to the bottom of Google's robots.txt help, you can see a similar example.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt